# SSRS 2008 - grouping sets?

Tags: sql, reporting-services, ssrs-2008, grouping, ssrs-grouping

If I have a `list object` which groups a `tablix` according to a country value in my dataset, is it possible to add my own custom combinations?

E.g. If I have UK, France, Germany, US, Japan boxes, and then one for EU which puts UK France and Germany in one group?

I can do this in `SQL Server 2008` with grouping sets, but can a similar thing be done in SSRS?

Comment: Please mention what you have tried so far.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a Calculated Field to your dataset (right-click on it). In the expression for it, use a Switch statement to decide the group name. Then you can use that Calculated Field in your report just like any other field.